# I am writing my first assignment and i cant seem figure out why i am unable to enter my first function

Tags: python-3.x

First of im sorry about bombarding my post with a bunch of code, but im putting it here hoping that it will help you guys understanding my question better.

I am trying to figure out why my IDE is unwilling to execute the first function of my code. Obviously im doing something wrong, but im to unexperienced to see it for myself. All help would be greatly appriciated.

If you have any further comments or tips on my code feel free contribute.

```
import random

print("Press '1' for New Single Player Game - Play against computer component: ")
print("Press '2' for New Two Player Game - Play against another person, using same computer: ")
print("Press '3' for Bonus Feature - A bonus feature of choice: ")
print("Press '4' for User Guide - Display full instructions for using your application: ")
print("Press '5' for Quit - Exit the program: ")

def choose_program():
    what_program = int(input("What program would you like to initiate?? Type in the 'number-value' from the chart above: "))
    if what_program == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5:
        program_choice = int(input("Make a choice: "))
        if (program_choice > 5) or (program_choice < 1):
            print("Please choose a number between 1 through 5 ")
            choose_program()
        elif program_choice == 1:
            print("You picked a New Single Player Game - Play against computer component")
            def single_player():
                start_game = input("Would you like to play 'ROCK PAPER SCISSORS LIZARD SPOCK'?? Type 'y' for YES, and 'n' for NO): ").lower()

                if start_game == "y":
                    print("Press '1' for Rock: ")
                    print("Press '2' for Paper: ")
                    print("Press '3' for Scissors: ")
                    print("Press '4' for Lizard: ")
                    print("Press '5' for Spock: ")

                elif start_game != "n":
                    print("Please type either 'y' for YES or 'n' for NO: ")
                    single_player()

            def player_one():
                human_one = int(input("Make a choice: "))
                if (human_one > 5) or (human_one < 1):
                    print("Please choose a number between 1 through 5 ")
                    player_one()
                elif human_one == 1:
                    print("You picked ROCK!")
                elif human_one == 2:
                    print("You picked PAPER!")
                elif human_one == 3:
                    print("You picked SCISSORS!")
                elif human_one == 4:
                    print("You picked LIZARD!")
                elif human_one == 5:
                    print("You picked SPOCK!")
                return human_one

            def computers_brain():
                cpu_one = random.randint(1, 5)
                if cpu_one == 1:
                    print("Computers choice iiiiiis ROCK!")
                elif cpu_one == 2:
                    print("Computers choice iiiiiis PAPER!")
                elif cpu_one == 3:
                    print("Computers choice iiiiiis SCISSORS!")
                elif cpu_one == 4:
                    print("Computers choice iiiiiis LIZARD!")
                elif cpu_one == 5:
                    print("Computers choice iiiiiis SPOCK!")
                return cpu_one

            def who_won(human, cpu, human_wins, cpu_wins, draw):
                if human == 1 and cpu == 3 or cpu == 4:
                    print("Human is invincible!!")
                    human_wins = human_wins.append(1)
                elif human == 2 and cpu == 1 or cpu == 5:
                    print("Human is invincible!!")
                    human_wins = human_wins.append(1)
                elif human == 3 and cpu == 2 or cpu == 4:
                    print("Human is invincible!!")
                    human_wins = human_wins.append(1)
                elif human == 4 and cpu == 2 or cpu == 5:
                    print("Human is invincible!!")
                    human_wins = human_wins.append(1)
                elif human == 5 and cpu == 1 or cpu == 3:
                    print("Human is invincible!!")
                    human_wins = human_wins.append(1)
                elif human == cpu:
                    print("Human & computer think alike, such technology")
                    draw = draw.append(1)
                else:
                    print("Computer have beaten it's master, incredible..")
                    cpu_wins = cpu_wins.append(1)
                return

            def end_score(human_wins, cpu_wins, draw):
                human_wins = sum(human_wins)
                cpu_wins = sum(cpu_wins)
                draw = sum(draw)
                print("Humans final score is: ", human_wins)
                print("Computers final score is: ", cpu_wins)
                print("Total draws: ", draw)

            def main():
                human = 0
                human_wins = []
                cpu = 0
                cpu_wins = []
                draw = []
                finalhuman_wins = 0
                finalcpu_wins = 0
                finaldraw = 0
                Continue = 'y'
                single_player()
                while Continue == 'y':
                    human = player_one()
                    cpu = computers_brain()
                    who_won(human, cpu, human_wins, cpu_wins, draw)
                    Continue = input("Would you like to play again (y/n):").lower()
                    if Continue == 'n':
                        print("Printing final scores.")
                        break
                end_score(human_wins, cpu_wins, draw)

            main()
        elif program_choice == 2:
            print("You picked a New Two Player Game - Play against another person, using same computer")
        elif program_choice == 3:
            print("You picked the Bonus Feature - A bonus feature of choice")
        elif program_choice == 4:
            print("You picked the User Guide - Display full instructions for using your application")
        elif program_choice == 5:
            print("You picked to Quit - Exit the program")
        return program_choice
    elif what_program != 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5:
        print("To initiate a program you need to type in the appropriate number to initiate this program, either 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5 ")
        choose_program()
```

Outout in IDE:

```
Press '1' for New Single Player Game - Play against computer component: 
Press '2' for New Two Player Game - Play against another person, using same computer: 
Press '3' for Bonus Feature - A bonus feature of choice: 
Press '4' for User Guide - Display full instructions for using your application: 
Press '5' for Quit - Exit the program: 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Perhaps add `choose_program()` to the end of the file?

Comment: Okay i got to admit i am a little embarrassed right now, but nevertheless, thank you very much :)

Comment: I've been through worse :)

Comment: Is this solved then?